# Can't show specific model field in my HTML template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

On my main page i want to show a category  just like

{{ post.body }} but instead {{ post.body }} would be  {{ post.category }}

here.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Articles{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
{% for post in post_list %}
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <span class="font-weight-bold"><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a> |
      </span> &middot;
      <span class="text-muted">by {{ post.author }} |
      {{ post.created_at }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <!-- Changes start here! -->
      <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
      <p>{{ post.category }}</p>
      <a href="{% url 'post_edit' post.pk %}">Edit</a> |
      <a href="{% url 'post_delete' post.pk %}">Delete</a> |
      <a href="{% url 'category_list' %}">Category</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
        <p>
          <span class="font-weight-bold">
            {{ comment.author }} &middot;
          </span>
          {{ comment }}
        </p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <!-- Changes end here! -->
  </div>
  <br />
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

but cannot to figure out how. But cannot figure out how.

Here is my models

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse("home")


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='categories')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})



class Comment(models.Model): 
    article = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_list")
```

Thanks in advance

Added

{{ post.category }}

in here

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Articles{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
{% for post in post_list %}
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <span class="font-weight-bold"><a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a> |
      </span> &middot;
      <span class="text-muted">by {{ post.author }} |
      {{ post.created_at }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <!-- Changes start here! -->
      <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
      <p>{{ post.category }}</p>
      <a href="{% url 'post_edit' post.pk %}">Edit</a> |
      <a href="{% url 'post_delete' post.pk %}">Delete</a> |
      <a href="{% url 'category_list' %}">Category</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
        <p>
          <span class="font-weight-bold">
            {{ comment.author }} &middot;
          </span>
          {{ comment }}
        </p>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <!-- Changes end here! -->
  </div>
  <br />
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

expected to see a category instead got post.category.None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the category in the HTML just like a property, you can add a property method in the model class and use it HTML, like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    
    @property
    def categories(self):
        return ', '.join([x.name for x in self.category.all()]
```

Then use it template like:

```
{{ post.categories }}
```

Alternatively as it is a [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) field, you can iterate through it in the template and render the categories:

```
{{ for c in post.category }} {{ c.name }} {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %} {{ endfor }}
```

---

Explanation of property method: [property method](https://realpython.com/python-property/) allows you to convert a function to an attribute of the object of that class. `self` in the property method refers to itself (or the object itself). using self.category.all(), you are accessing the manytomany relation between Post and Category class. I am running a loop and access each of the Category objects connected to the Post object (the main object which are using in the template/html) and I am joining the names of the Category objects' names to form a comma separated string.

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to solve this problem for a week. If you don't mind, can you please explain the answer

Comment: I added explanation for the property method